# Base href URL html5

Tags: html, href

I have a website like [www.site.com](http://www.site.com), I used languages on it:

```
https://www.example.com/en/dashboard.html
https://www.example.com/es/dashboard.html
https://www.example.com/fr/dashboard.html
https://www.example.com/de/dashboard.html
```

And I am using a base href url:

```
<base href="www.site.com/">
```

If I call a css file or a js file such as:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap-4.5.0.min.css">
```

It give that the file does NOT exists, when I check the source code and click on that file, I follow to the below url:

```
https://www.example.com/en/assets/css/bootstrap-4.5.0.min.css
```

However files are under root domain:

```
/home/site/www/assets/css/bootstrap-4.5.0.min.css
```

Not under all languages.

So can I call these files to have a url like this, without language code:

```
https://www.example.com/assets/css/bootstrap-4.5.0.min.css
```

Comment: You forgot to add `https://` in front of the URL.

Comment: And if you add a front slash at the begining of the href? `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/bootstrap-4.5.0.min.css">`

Comment: If I use an absolute URL or slash in href, the slick carousel does NOT work, it is coming an image under another image an so on: https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/